# In vscode editor after adding the cucumber feature file line appears in different format

Tags: visual-studio-code, cucumber, cypress-cucumber-preprocessor

In `vscode` editor, I have typed the feature file line and vs code display the autosuggestion, once I choose from the autosuggestion, below line gets added in editor in following broken format, `And I click on the ("|')[^\1]*\1 action link`. Could someone please advise the issue here ?

Original feature file line is as follows; `And I click on the "Add" action link`

Below is my `settings.json` file;

```
{
    "cucumberautocomplete.steps": [
        "tests/cypress/integration/**/*.js",
        "cypress/integration/**/*.js"
     ],
     "cucumberautocomplete.customParameters": [
         
     ],
     "cucumberautocomplete.onTypeFormat": true,
"cucumberautocomplete.formatConfOverride": {

},
"git.ignoreWindowsGit27Warning": true,
"cucumberautocomplete.pages": {},
"git.enableSmartCommit": true,
"git.confirmSync": false,
"git.autofetch": true,
"diffEditor.ignoreTrimWhitespace": false
}
```

Versions:

```
 cypress-cucumber-preprocessor: "^2.5.5",
 VS code : 1.65.2
 Operating system: Ubuntu 20.04
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: `Original feature file line is as follows` you probably mean: **what I want to type**, the autosuggest is suggesting the line used in your steps code files to match the feature file line, they fail to make it a snippet suggestion and make snippet fields of the regex part, what is the matching step code, the suggested regex does not have a useful capture group

Comment: Yes, in the step definition its is a normal `string`.  In PHP storm,the auto suggestion works fine...after adding the line from the suggestion list..it displays as follows `And I click on the <string> action link` and you can replace the `<string>` with desired string in double quotes....

Comment: But in VS Code after adding the line,`And I click on the ("|')[^\1]*\1 action link` it appears to be broken. Any way to fix this ? Am I missing any settings ?

Comment: I have added screen shot on how does it look in suggestion list and adding from the list how does it appear. After adding it broke the next assertion line too

Comment: The suggestion is `I click on the {string} action link`, this is the text from the step code file, the extension replaces `{string}` with a regex that matches a string, not what you want in a feature file, a literal replacement with the suggested text is better, create an issue at the extension repo, it is easy to modify